# Is there any way to remove all CR LF characters from html file using ant

Tags: ant

I have tried a bunch of things but nothing is working for me. I have tried "fixcrlf" also but it is giving me error related to temp file renaming in temp directory. I will be very thankful if anyone can help me out with any sort of solution.

```
<project name="extractElement" default="test0">

<target name = "test0">
    <antcall target = "test1"/>
    <antcall target = "test"/>
</target>
<target name="test1">
    <copy file="E:\backup\latest report\Report-20160523_2036.html" toFile="E:\backup\latest report\Report-20160523_2036_1.html"/>

</target>
<target name="test">
    <fixcrlf srcdir="E:\backup\latest report" includes="Report-20160523_2036_1.html"
    eol="lf" eof="remove" />

    <replaceregexp file="E:\backup\latest report\Report-20160523_2036_1.html"
       match="\n" 
       flags="g"
       replace=" " />
</target>


</project>
```

This is the code that I am trying to execute.

Comment: Using `<fixcrlf>` sounds like the right thing to do. What error message are you getting?

Comment: <fixcrlf srcdir="E:\backup\latest report" includes="Report-20160523_2036_1.html"
         eol="lf" eof="remove" />


I used this code, it is throwing an error saying "error running fixcrlf on file E:\backup\latest report\Report-20160523_2036_1.html"

Comment: I successfully removed CR how can I remove LS

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted to delete all newline characters from the file. You probably want to use the [`<deletecharacters>` filter](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#deletecharacters) instead.

Comment: I found what the problem is.
Actually first I'm copying a file to some new location, and then I am removing all CR an LF. But what I saw is, there is some lock on newly created file so ant is not able to remove this lock. Is there any way to remove this lock

Comment: Another possibility is to use a [`<replacetoken>` nested under a `<replace>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html).

Comment: If you have any example please post. It will be very helpful for me.